# React iterate props in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I was new in `React`, and I am confusing about iterating props data in `JSX`.

Assume the `this.props.data` is

```
[
  [
    "2017-1",
    {
      title: "title1"
      describe: "des1"
    }
  ],
  [
    "2017-2",
    {
      title: "title2"
      describe: "des2" 
    }
  ],...
]
```

How do I iterate data in table？

I was hoping it will render some kind of like this

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>2017-1</td>
    <td>title1</td>
    <td>des1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2017-2</td>
    <td>title2</td>
    <td>des2</td>
  </tr>
  ...
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would map it. I'm assuming that the format will always be the same (out of laziness).

(Please do not run the snippet, it is only for formatting)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gL8drpyd/1/

```js
var data = [
  [
    "2017-1",
    {
      title: "title1"
      describe: "des1"
    }
  ],
  [
    "2017-2",
    {
      title: "title2"
      describe: "des2" 
    }
  ]
];

let rows = data.map( (item) => 
  (
    <tr>
      <td>{item[0]}</td>
      <td>{item[1].title}</td>
      <td>{item[1].describe}</td>
    </tr>
  )
);

// put this in the <tbody> in render

<tbody>
  {rows}
</tbody>
```